# Does vim has own escape function for `set stl` value?

Tags: vim, escaping

I need to set title for vim window `:setl stl=$title`.

```
$ title='It is b.c';
$ vim $file -c "setl stl=${title}";
```

Unfortunately, `set stl` doesn't support some special character such as `space`. I have to escape the special chars first.

```
$ vim $file -c "setl stl=${title// /\ }";//It\ is\ b.c
```

What I want to know is about:

> Is there any convenient method for this problem?Does vim has own escape function for stl value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim does have an escape function. It is called `escape()`. (Take a look at `:h escape()`). You can use this in combination with `execute` (`:h exec`) to set `stl` properly.

```
vim $file -c "exec 'setl stl='.escape('${title}', ' ')"
```

The vim command for this specific example is

```
:echo escape('It is b.c', ' ')
It\ is\ b.c
```

So you can use execute to construct the string properly. Where `.` is used for string concatenation.

```
:exec 'setl stl=' . escape('It is b.c', ' ')
```

---

Simpler solution from @NikitaKouevda is the following. (`:h let-&`)

```
vim $file -c "let &l:stl = '${title}'"
```

And since vim can read environment variables itself you can simplify it further.

```
vim $file -c 'let &l:stl=$title'
```

Comment: You can also use `let` (i.e. `vim $file -c "let &l:stl = '${title}'"`) to avoid both `escape` and `exec`.

Comment: `'let &l:stl=$title'` only works if `$title` has been `export`ed since it relies on vim evaluating the variable (in the double-quoted varieties, `$title` is expanded by the shell before being passed to vim as an argument).